# jQuery - How to find if all matching elements are display:none?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a list of divs similar to the simplified code below, which I've set up with a filter via a dropdown (so if you select an option in the drop down, all of the divs that don't match are set to display:none).

```
<div id="productlist">
   <div class="product book">Title</div>
   <div class="product book">Title</div>
   <div class="product game">Title</div>
   <div class="product movie">Title</div>
   <div class="product game">Title</div>
</div>
```

In the event that there are no matches however, I'd like to display a message stating as such.

Is there a way of setting an if statement, that if all divs that match the class "product" (or if all immediate children of #productlist) are set to display:none, to show the message?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is achieved through the use of the `:visible` selector and the `.length` method such as so

```
if ($('.product:visible').length == 0)
{
    alert('No visible products found.');
}
```

Comment: Great! Thankyou.

I ended up setting it to run when the select element (which is what is used to filter) is changed, with an else statement to hide the message when not needed.

`$('select').change(function(){`
`if ($('.product:visible').length == 0) {$('#none').show();}`
`else {$('#none').hide();}`
`});`

Comment: @Nathan Welcome to StackOverflow! If this solves your question, please mark the question as answered by checking the box next to this answer. This will boost your reputation. Again, welcome to the community!

Comment: Probably worth noting the documentation suggests selecting the elements first, then `.filter`ing on `:visible` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `is` method makes your intent quite clear:

```
if (!$('.product').is(':visible')) {
  alert('No visible products found.');
}
```

`is(':visible')` returns true if *any* of the selected divs is visible, so the `if(!$('.product').is(':visible'))` statement will fire only none of the divs are visible.